# How to test an installed SSL Certificate before a domain resolves to the server

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, dns-zone

Is it posisble to test an SSL Cert through a browser that is installed on a server before the DNS has been updated to point that domain to its new server?

I am looking to do something like what the DigiCert online SSL Checker does.

I have a host "example.com" resolving to Server A.

I purchased an SSL Cert and installed it on Server B where the host will soon resolve.

Before I update the DNS to re-point example.com from Server A over to Server B, I want to know if the SSL Certificate works properly with its installed key, certificate, and bundle.

Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest [`testssl.sh`](https://testssl.sh/) for a fairly comprehensive sanity check of your TLS/SSL setup.

You can direct it to a specific IP rather than resolving the name, like so:

```
./testssl.sh --ip 192.0.2.1 https://www.example.com/
```

In addition to this, for instance if you want to do functional tests with a web browser or other software that may not have similar functionality, simply override name resolution using `/etc/hosts` while doing the tests.

Comment: Nice utility! <filler>

Comment: looks like a great tool to use. but I get `./testssl.sh: command not found`. Do you know where it is located @HåkanLindqvist?

Comment: @H.Ferrence What did you do so far?

Comment: I did `sudo ./testssl.sh --ip 112.456.789.012 https://example.com/` and got **./testssl.sh: command not found**. Then I did `sudo testssl.sh --ip 112.456.789.012 https://example.com/` and got **testssl.sh: command not found**.

Comment: @H.Ferrence What did you do to install / download / otherwise get `testssl.sh`? Also, there should be no need for `sudo`.

Comment: I did nothing except assume it was part of the *nix CentOS server. Sorry -- my bad...

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just add the needed name to your `/etc/hosts` to override DNS.

Comment: I did that but the DigiCert tool reported the cert that was installed on Server A, not server B

Comment: Why do you need to use Digicert at all? Just use `openssl s_client` locally, along with testing it in your browser.

Comment: I am trying to troubleshoot the inability to restart apache and the http daemon. I cannot easily diagnose if my httpd.conf directives are in error or if the SSL Cert's Key, Certificate and Bundle are not working together properly.

Comment: If you have issues restarting Apache, you need to study its log files.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a request with curl.  Something like this perhaps.  The `--resolve` option defines a name/ip/port mapping for that command.

```
curl \
     --resolve www.example.org:80:192.0.2.153 \
     --resolve www.example.org:443:192.0.2.153 \
     https://www.example.org/
```